# Drawing rectangular labels in d3

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, label

I want to make labels for my d3 bar graph like so:

[image: Labels]

But I'm having a really hard time writing the code to generate these in d3. Can anyone help me out?

Below is the snippet I'm using to generate the bars - but not sure how much that helps here. I can write html to make the labels as depicted in the picture, but this makes it impossible to align the bars to the labels as far as I know.

```
canvas.selectAll('rect-total')
  .data(projectData)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', w-50)
  .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
  .attr('x', 20)
  .attr('y', function(d) {return yScale(d.category);})
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke', function(d) {return categoryColorsDict[d.category];});


canvas.selectAll('rect-success')
  .data(projectData)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', function(d) {return xScale(d.successful_projects);})
  .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
  .attr('y', function(d) {return yScale(d.category);})
  .attr('x', function(d) {return 20;})
  .attr('fill', function(d) {return categoryColorsDict[d.category];});
```

Comment: Can you include the code for the bar graph that you wrote?

Comment: Added but not sure how much it helps

Comment: It looks like you have the rectangles already. All you need to do now is add the `text` elements in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Lars mentioned I believe it should be something similar to the below:

```
canvas.selectAll('text')
.data([ArrayOfData])
.enter()
.append('text')
.attr('y', function(d) {return yScale(d.category);})
.attr('x', function(d) {return 20;})
.text(function(d) {return d;})
.attr('text-anchor','middle').
.style({What ever styles you want to apply});
```

Hope this helps!